How can I manage dependencies with FlatPak?
I have some trouble understanding how dependencies are managed within FlatPak. Recently I wanted to update all FlatPaks using flatpak update and got a message that some software version is not supported anymore. My idea was to update the software and to delete the not supported version. However when I tried uninstalling the not supported version, FlatPak wanted also to uninstall dependencies. What is the best way to update from a non-supported version?
